# Вывод графика в файл на с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Задача такая: создать генератор случайных чисел конгруэнтным методом(уже сделал) и вывести графическую характеристику(распределение на плоскости(элементы попарно обрабатываются как точки с координатами x и y)) в файл. Именно с этим и возникла проблема, не могу найти решения как реализовать этот вывод.

У меня есть реализация распределения на плоскости(нахождение х и у).

```
 while(true){
X=rand();
Y[X].count+=1;
}
```

Но как их вывести в виде графика?

Comment: Это что-то вроде гистограммы? Или точек на плоскости? В каком формате выводить - текст, или какой-то jpg?

Comment: Это должны быть точки на плоскости. В ТЗ не написано какого типа файл, но обычно у меня в ТЗ файл имеется в виду обычный блокнот, но как я понимаю это в блоктнот невозможно вывести

Comment: Ну почему? Звездочки и пробелы, например. Но все равно непонятно, что вы хотите — вот с этим: `Y[X].count+=1;`

Comment: Если в .txt, то только символами (например, '*'). Если требуется графика, то самый простой формат - .bmp. Создаёте массив точек в формате RGB, или просто char (для 8-битного изображения), заполняете его вашей графикой, формируете структуру BITMAPINFO и пишете всё это в bmp-файл. Подробнее про формат BMP - см. гугл.

Comment: Кстати, bmp-изображение можно сгенерировать средствами GDI (графическое API для Windows). Однако что-то мне подсказывает, от вас требуется всё таки текстовая реализация.

Comment: Можно сгенерировать .svg изображение. Это и текстовый файл и картинка, просматриваемая стандартными средствами.